# Como utilizar texto do botão clicado pelo usuário como input no tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, eventos

Eu gostaria de utilizar o texto do botão clicado pelo usuário do meu jogo para fazer um teste lógico e retornar outra pergunta para o usuário. O jogo vai funcionar com uma sequência dessas perguntas, e as respostas possíveis são sempre "sim" e "não".

Para isso, eu gostaria de pegar o texto do botão clicado entre os botões presentes no meu Frame de botões. Só descobri como pegar o texto de um botão específico com o comando `my_button['text']`.

O código do jogo é muito grande, então fiz um [EMCV](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) que apresento abaixo. A parte comentada seria equivalente ao teste lógico que quero implementar, mas ainda não consegui.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import random

def start_game():
    n = random.sample(range(5000),1)[0]
    text_widget4.insert('1.0', '{} é um número é par?'.format(str(n)))
    #essa parte não está funcionando
    # resto = n%%2
    # if (resto==0) & (button_w4['text'] = 'Yes'):
    #     text_widget4.insert('2.0', 'Você está certo')
    # elif (resto==0) & (button_w4['text'] = 'No'):
    #     text_widget4.insert('2.0', 'Você está certo')

class Fourth_window(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title('Meu jogo')
        self.resizable(False, False)

class Button_Frame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container):
        super().__init__(container)
        #BUTTON YES
        yes_button = ttk.Button(self, text = 'Yes')
        yes_button.pack(side = 'left', padx =5, pady = 5, fill = 'x')

        #BUTTON NO
        no_button = ttk.Button(self, text = 'No')
        no_button.pack(side = 'left', padx =5, pady = 5, fill = 'x')

class Quit_Frame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container, label_1, function_1):
        super().__init__(container)
        self.label_1 = label_1
        self.function_1 = function_1

        next_button = ttk.Button(self, text = label_1, command = function_1)
        next_button.pack(side = 'top', padx =5, pady = 5, fill = 'x')

        quit_button = ttk.Button(self, text = 'Quit', command = root.destroy)
        quit_button.pack(side = 'top', padx =5, pady = 5, fill = 'x')



root = Fourth_window()

text_w4 = ttk.Frame(root)
text_w4.pack(side = 'top', fill = 'both', expand = True)

text_widget4 = tk.Text(text_w4)
text_widget4.pack()

button_w4 = Button_Frame(root)
button_w4.pack(side = 'bottom')


quit_w4 = Quit_Frame(root, 'Start', start_game)
quit_w4.pack(side = 'right')

root.mainloop()
```

**EDIT:** No caso concreto, o que quero fazer é transformar um executável que roda no terminal em uma GUI. Link para o executável no [github](https://github.com/lucascr91/brecht_0.0.2/blob/master/words.py)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma solução possível é criar duas novas funções: uma para gerar novas perguntas e outra associada ao botões `Sim` e `Não` para validar as respostas.

É necessário também tornar a variável `numero` numa variável `global`-

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import random

def adiciona_pergunta():
    global numero
    numero = random.sample(range(5000),1)[0]
    text_widget4.insert('1.0', '{} é um número é par?\n'.format(str(numero)))

def valida_resposta(bool):
    global numero
    if (bool and (numero % 2) == 0) or (bool == False and (numero % 2) != 0):
        text_widget4.insert('2.0', 'Você está certo!\n')
    else:
        text_widget4.insert('2.0', 'Você está errado!\n')

class Fourth_window(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title('Meu jogo')
        self.resizable(False, False)

class Button_Frame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container):
        super().__init__(container)
        #BUTTON YES
        yes_button = ttk.Button(self, text = 'Yes', command=lambda: valida_resposta(True))
        yes_button.pack(side = 'left', padx =5, pady = 5, fill = 'x')

        #BUTTON NO
        no_button = ttk.Button(self, text = 'No', command=lambda: valida_resposta(False))
        no_button.pack(side = 'left', padx =5, pady = 5, fill = 'x')

class Quit_Frame(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, container, label_1, function_1):
        super().__init__(container)
        self.label_1 = label_1
        self.function_1 = function_1

        next_button = ttk.Button(self, text = label_1, command = function_1)
        next_button.pack(side = 'top', padx =5, pady = 5, fill = 'x')

        quit_button = ttk.Button(self, text = 'Quit', command = root.destroy)
        quit_button.pack(side = 'top', padx =5, pady = 5, fill = 'x')


root = Fourth_window()
numero = 0 #inicializa a variavel global

text_w4 = ttk.Frame(root)
text_w4.pack(side = 'top', fill = 'both', expand = True)

text_widget4 = tk.Text(text_w4)
text_widget4.pack()

button_w4 = Button_Frame(root)
button_w4.pack(side = 'bottom')


quit_w4 = Quit_Frame(root, 'Start', adiciona_pergunta)
quit_w4.pack(side = 'right')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Interessante. É uma boa saída, mas nesse caso, o programa não faz a pergunta novamente e, como disse na pergunta, precisaria que ele encadeasse uma série de perguntas. Vou editar meu código para incluir um link para meu problema real

Comment: Não sei se percebi a tua dúvida. Caso queiras que o programa faça uma nova pergunta quando o utilizador acerta na resposta é só adicionar `adiciona_pergunta()` dentro do `if` da função `validar_resposta`...